# Console linq query takes more time compared to SSMS

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, ssms

Testing a EF6 linq query in an console application. Here are the details:

```
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

            db.Database.Log = Console.Write;
            db.Users.Where(x => x.GroupId == 1407).ToList();  //Approx 7000 rows

            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

From the output in console window:
On an average the query took 192 ms to execute. However, the open and close time of connection was about 7 secs. This was also reflected in `ElapsedMilliseconds` log.

Moreover, I ran the same generated query in SSMS and it took same time to execute and the output was materialized in avg 3 secs.

Given the above information I have 2 questions:

1. If the execution takes just about 200 ms why does it take more time for the data to materialize? (I guess its because of the internet connection and data being downloaded client side. Not sure though)
2. Why is there such a huge difference in time between SSMS and Console app?

Comment: Answer to question 2: "Because SSMS doesn't use Entity Framework".

Comment: @Richardissimo more precision: SSMS doesn't do materialization (transforming each retrieved line into an object instance and/or track them)

Comment: Test by disabling EF traking.

Comment: Tried running with `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` no change in time.